# RMI in java 17 WAR project. How do I fix this error?

Tags: java, rmi, corba, iiop

I am struggling to update my company's code from java 8 to 17. I have already added dependencies but the code uses RMI which was inbuilt in jdk 8 but its not available in jdk 11 and 17.

The codebase is a WAR project using tomcat 8.5 and active mq.

this is the error -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:401)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:188)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:220)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:153)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.loadDelegateClass(PortableRemoteObject.java:206)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.createDelegateIfSpecified(PortableRemoteObject.java:183)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.<clinit>(PortableRemoteObject.java:63)
    at org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionImpl.makeSubCoord(TransactionImpl.java:1086)
    at org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionImpl.registerSynchronization(TransactionImpl.java:695)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.registerSynchronizationIfPossible(JDBCContext.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.checkTransactionSynchStatus(SessionImpl.java:2112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.isOpen(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy39.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:232)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy46.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy47.findDetailsByPropertyKeyInString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy48.findDetailsByPropertyKeyInString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy152.getFTIDLoginEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.fetchCreateAndSetSession(Application.java:1529)
    at org.apache.wicket.Session.get(Session.java:156)
    at org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException$InterceptData.get(RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException.java:146)
    at org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException$1.matchedData(RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException$1.getCompatibilityScore(RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException.java:180)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.CompoundRequestMapper.mapRequest(CompoundRequestMapper.java:123)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.resolveRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:184)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:209)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)`
```

Sadly I cannot share the code because I am not allowed to, I used glassfish-cobra because cobra was removed from jdk as well.

Things I have tried - Spent 6 hours searching for anything on google, 4-5 hours of asking chatgpt if it could help me.

I haven't tried creating a security manager because I have no idea what I am doing, I am just an intern and this is my first job, I am not even good at java so I avoided that for now.

Also yes I have already checked similar posts to this and no they werent of any help to me. A few of them say to just create a security manager but idk how to do it or make it work in this huge codebase.

Comment: RMI/IIOP was removed from the JDK at some point. I don't know what the solution is. Maybe you can obtain it as a separate JAR somehow.

Comment: @user207421 I need an OMG API dependency and RMI dependency. I have tried a lot of jars but I end up with the same error

Comment: Well keep looking. And forget about the security manager, nothing to do with it, or with any of the questions you found it in either. See [JEP 320](https://openjdk.org/jeps/320), if you can make head or tail of it. Anyway all this started many years ago.

Comment: @user207421 I dont need security manger? Can you tell me some other dependency i can use then? because i cant seem to find any

Comment: No, you don't need the security manager, as I've already said, and no I can't tell you anything else you can use either, which I've already said twice. Maybe your CORBA vendor has something.

Comment: @user207421 alright ill try to find something else again. thanks

Comment: NB The RMI security manager is (a) obsolete, (b) not applicable to RMI/IIOP, and (c) only required with RMI/JRMP (the default) if you are also using the codebase feature. Most people misinterpret the corresponding error message to mean that they need the security manager when they don't. In your case you don't even have that particular message in the first place.

Comment: @user207421 well I removed the glassfish api and have tried like 5-6 more for rmi and now it just says rmi/portableremoteobject class not found, even tho it exists when I search it up using ctrl+shift+T in eclipse. I even added it in my tomcat lib folder but it still not using it

Comment: I don't know why you think removing things is going to help.

Comment: @user207421 then what do i do lol, you have told me what not to do but that doesnt help

Comment: I have told you to keep looking for an implementation. I didn't say a word about removing things. That was your idea.

Comment: @user207421 i dont understand dude, I have literally checked every maven dependecny for this, its not working, wdym keep looking for implementation